# In css while declaring a "background image" with "height: auto" image is not displaying

Tags: css

```
#test {background-image: url('/Skins/slickv2/csdlrsite/shared/1dpt_img_mainpic.png');
                  width: 200px; 
                 height: auto; 
     background-repeat : no-repeat;}
```

this is not displaying the image . but if we change the height option to some value it is working , can any one help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height:auto auto sizes the div to the height of the content. A background image is not content, so the div height is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct as in the answer above div will be effected to that property, more over i am not sure but may be due to: for the background image first to check whether it is applied or not give the actual size(h and w) of the actual image...

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesnt count Background image Height in the "auto" detection. only things like texte, other blocks and such ...